# Colocar máscara em @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

No banco de dados, o campo CPF é bigint e long na model. Tenho dois problemas com isso:
1) Se o cpf começar com 0 ou 00, ele não vai gravar isso e então, para exibir na tela, terei que usar algon como padleft(11) ou similiar.
2) Como eu tenho um cshtml que foi gerado basedo na model, então eu não estou conseguindo gerar a máscara no campo para digitar o cpf. O problema é que no banco, terei tamanhos de campos diferentes, para quando o cpf começar com 0 ou 00 e assim vai, sei que isso não seria o problemas, graças ao padleft(11).

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cpf, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cpf, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cpf" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cpf, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Com o código acima, não estou conseguindo mascarar o campo, pelas razões já apresentadas. Alguém sugere?

Comment: por que não funcionou, deu erro? os elementos são encontrados pelo seletor?

Comment: Erro não deu, mas a máscara não carregou.

Comment: Apenas como dica e com todas as boas intenções. Reveja a sua participação no site pnet. Esforce-se por deixar as perguntas o mais claras possíveis logo desde que as abre. Inclua sempre os erros que elas dão, o que você tentou em código, porque motivo não funciona, qual você acha que pode ser a solução, etc etc. Lembre-se que para alem de as suas perguntas o ajudarem a si, também devem ajudar qualquer leitor que tenha uma duvida similar. Pegando nesta por exemplo, você fez a pergunta mais ou menos assim "Tenho este código e dá erro, alguem tem ideia de como corrigir ?"

Comment: (...) Se você nem disse o erro que deu, nem o que está a tentar fazer, como é que alguem irá conseguir ajudar ? Isso força a que quem quer responder tenha que fazer vários comentarios até se conseguir inteirar, ou a responder com algo que não era o que você queria.

Comment: Fiz uma edição e veja qua agora eu consigo alguma coisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa incluir a referência do script do [Jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) na sua  `View`.

```js
$("#cpf").inputmask("mask", {
  "mask": "999.999.999-99"
}, {
  reverse: true
});
$("#nascimento").inputmask("mask", {
  "mask": "99/99/9999"
}, {
  reverse: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<p>CPF: <input type="text" id="cpf" /></p>
<p>Nascimento: <input type="text" id="nascimento" /></p>
```

Comment: Funcionou agora apenas a data. Cpf não

Comment: Claro, CPF é numérico. Como eu faço em casos assim, atribuir uma máscara e quando eu gravar, apenas números?

Comment: @pnet para remover a máscara no submit use removeMaskOnSubmit. Na documentação tem todas as opções que o plugin aceita: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask